# Using WS2812b Addressable LEDs on Raspberry Pis

Tags: raspberry-pi, ws2812b

I am attempting to control WS2812b LEDs using a raspberry pi according to this guide: https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/connect-control-raspberry-pi-ws2812-rgb-led-strips/

So far I executed the following lines in terminal without any issue:

```
git clone https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x
cd rpi_ws281x/
sudo scons
cd python
```

However when I try to execute the next couple of lines, I receive errors:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/rpi_ws281x/python $ python setup.py build
Extracting in /tmp/tmpMzL9XM
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    use_setuptools()
  File "/home/pi/rpi_ws281x/python/ez_setup.py", line 161, in use_setuptools
    return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
  File "/home/pi/rpi_ws281x/python/ez_setup.py", line 120, in _do_download
    _build_egg(egg, archive, to_dir)
  File "/home/pi/rpi_ws281x/python/ez_setup.py", line 62, in _build_egg
    with archive_context(archive_filename):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/home/pi/rpi_ws281x/python/ez_setup.py", line 100, in archive_context
    with ContextualZipFile(filename) as archive:
  File "/home/pi/rpi_ws281x/python/ez_setup.py", line 88, in __new__
    return zipfile.ZipFile(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 770, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 811, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file"
zipfile.BadZipfile: File is not a zip file
pi@raspberrypi:~/rpi_ws281x/python $ python setup.py install
Extracting in /tmp/tmplrNAMs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    use_setuptools()
  File "/home/pi/rpi_ws281x/python/ez_setup.py", line 161, in use_setuptools
    return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
  File "/home/pi/rpi_ws281x/python/ez_setup.py", line 120, in _do_download
    _build_egg(egg, archive, to_dir)
  File "/home/pi/rpi_ws281x/python/ez_setup.py", line 62, in _build_egg
    with archive_context(archive_filename):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/home/pi/rpi_ws281x/python/ez_setup.py", line 100, in archive_context
    with ContextualZipFile(filename) as archive:
  File "/home/pi/rpi_ws281x/python/ez_setup.py", line 88, in __new__
    return zipfile.ZipFile(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 770, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 811, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file"
zipfile.BadZipfile: File is not a zip file
```

Does anyone have any idea on what I should do?

Comment: Did you try [this??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083235/unzipping-file-results-in-badzipfile-file-is-not-a-zip-file). How is this an EE question!!?

Comment: Because this is not a coding question, duh.

Comment: Verify that the GPIO's are turning on or off with a volt meter. Post a schematic

Comment: Next time, consider posting questions about RPi-specific software at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Found the error, the guides assumes RPis operating with python 3 by default, even though my RPi is using python 2. To fix execute `python3 setup.py build` and so on instead of `python setup.py build`.